# MS Access load text box with multiple values from other form

Tags: ms-access, expression

I've got a quick Access database update I need to do and it's been years since I've touched Access. What I need to do is take a text box, and have it pre load with two values from another form. So far I've tried just adding them from the controls menu and I get nothing but errors. In the data menu on the property sheet, I edit the control source and put the following:

= «Expr» Forms![AFR]![SerialNo]

so I'm trying to load the SerialNo field value from the form AFR. But I get the error message "The expression you entered contains invalid syntax. You may have entered an operand without an operator."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Access has tried to be helpful, and entered the "" in for you which is not needed. You should use this instead, probably as the default value:

```
=[Forms]![AFR]![SerialNo]
```

Note that if form AFR is not open when the second form is opened, then you will get an error of "#Name?".